# How to add methods dynamically to laravel class

Tags: laravel

I have a Convo class. I need to add fun_1(), fun_2(), fun_3().... dynamically to the class and call them when needed like the code below:

```
class Convo {

    protected $functions;

    public function fun_builder()
    {
       $functions = Function::where('published',true)->get();

       //there will be values fun_1,fun_2,fun_3.... from the $functions->fun_fields   

    }

    public function fun_1() { }
    public function fun_2() { }
    public function fun_3() { }
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with magic method in php

```
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        return (new)->$method(...$parameters);
    }
```

If the class does not have a function with this name , this method will be call.

you can make dynamic method with this ability.